# SciPy installation fails: quadpack error

Tags: python, scipy, atlas

I tried to install scipy on my user account ~/local using both easy_install and the 'python setup.py install' method with source files. I get this error:

```
error: Setup script exited with error:
Command "gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
-fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE
-fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector
--param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC
-I/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.6
-c scipy/integrate/_quadpackmodule.c
-o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/scipy/integrate/_quadpackmodule.o"
failed with exit status 1
```

I'm using 'gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC)'. Could this issue be related to the compiler or python2.6 version? Otherwise what could I check?

Thanks!

F.

Comment: Don't you get more information when the compilation fails? Have you checked you have the required dependencies (Atlas+LAPACK, `python-devel`, `gfortran`)? In RHEL5 I think the right package name is `atlas`, so check it is available to you.

Comment: What is the output of `python setup.py config`?

Comment: @Salem @ali_m thanks for the answers, I installed LAPACK+BLAS, but not ATLAS. Since it seems quite tricky to install (I have not root access to turn off CPU throttling), I'll contact the system administrator.
Plus, `python setup.py config` showed also that I'm using a not-recommended version of numpy (too old).